# How to use custom values in Symfony 2.7 choice form field instead of numbers

Tags: forms, symfony

I am struggling with using `choice` form fields in Symfony 2.7. The goal is to let the user select some very basic options:

**Data Object**

```
class MyDataObj {
    protected $option = null;

    public function getOption() {
        return $this->option;
    }

    public function setOption($option) {
        $this->option = $option;
    }
}
```

**Form creation within some controller**:

```
...
$dataObject = new MyDataObject();
$form = $this->createForm('custom_data_type', $dataObject);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

**The custom FormType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('option', 'choice', array(
            ...
            'choices' => array(
                'Option A' => 'option_value_1',
                'Option B' => 'option_value_2',
                'Option C' => 'option_value_3',
                ),
            'choices_as_values' => true,   
        ));

    ...
}
```

The rendered Result:

```
<select id="custom_data_type_option" class="form-control" name="custom_data_type[option]">
    <option value="0">Option A</option>
    <option value="1">Option B</option>        
    <option value="2">Option C</option>
</select>
```

So the Options get the values 0-2 instead of `option_value_N`. How can I change this?

I already tried to add a `choice_value` callback. However, the result was even more irritating :

```
->add('option', 'choice', array(
    ...
    'choices' => array(
        'Option A' => 'option_value_1',
        'Option B' => 'option_value_2',
        'Option C' => 'option_value_3',
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,  
    'choice_value' => function ($allChoices, $currentChoiceKey) { 
        if (null === $currentChoiceKey) 
            return 'nothing';

        if ('Option A' === $currentChoiceKey) 
            return 'option_value_1';

        if ('Option B' === $currentChoiceKey) 
            return 'option_value_2';

        if ('Option C' === $currentChoiceKey) 
            return 'option_value_3'; 

        return 'unknown';
    }
));

THE RESULT:
<select id="custom_data_type_option" class="form-control" name="custom_data_type[option]">
    <option value="nothing">Option C</option>
    <option value="nothing">Option C</option>        
    <option value="nothing">Option C</option>
</select>
```

I do understand, that before Symfony 2.7 the handling was different and a choice `key => value` was rendered as `<option value="key">value</option>`. To turn of this behaviour in Symfony 2.7 the `'choices_as_values' => true` option has to be used.

But I do not understand, why the values are not simply used as specified in `choices` (which is a `key => value` array)...

And what is wrong with the `choice_value` callback that delivers such a strange result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the Options get the values 0-2 instead of option_value_N. How can I change this?

The way to generate the "choices" option has changed since the version 2.7, if the `choice_value` option is `null`, an incrementing integer is used as the value.

> And what is wrong with the choice_value callback that delivers such a strange result?

if you need to keep the values in the final `<select>` then only have to do this:

```
->add('option', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Option A' => 'option_value_1',
        'Option B' => 'option_value_2',
        'Option C' => 'option_value_3',
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    // this will keep the same functionality as before
    'choice_value' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
        return $value;
    }
));

THE RESULT:
<select id="custom_data_type_option" class="form-control" name="custom_data_type[option]">
    <option value="option_value_1">Option C</option>
    <option value="option_value_2">Option C</option>
    <option value="option_value_3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Refs:

- http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14825/files

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do and it's working well (but Symfony 2.8). I defined my array without reversing keys and use the php `array_flip()` method :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$myArray = [
    'option_value_1' => 'Option A',
    'option_value_2' => 'Option B',
    'option_value_3' => 'Option C',
];

$builder->add('mySelect', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => array_flip($myArray),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
]);
```

The rendering using Twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.mySelect) }}
```

PS: advice: avoid using names as 'option' as varaiable or key names...